# Interaction picture for spin-operator $J_x$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I try to find a simple way or even an explicit expression for interaction representation
$$J_x(t):=e^{iJ_zt}J_xe^{-iJ_zt},$$
where $J_x, J_z$ are spin-operators for arbitary spin $j$. I have tried to compute it in eigen basis of $J_z$, i. e. $\{|j, j\rangle, |j, j-1\rangle, |j, j-2\rangle, ..., |j, -j\rangle\}$, but it wasn't successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably aware of the fundamental ("Hadamard") [adjoint action lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula), or can easily prove it,
$$
e^A B e^{-A}= B +[A,B]+ \tfrac{1}{2!}[A,[A,B]]+ \tfrac{1}{3!}[A,[A,[A,B]]]+... ,
$$
leading to
$$
e^{itJ_z} J_x e^{-itJ_z} = J_x -tJ_y - \tfrac{t^2}{2!} J_x +\tfrac{t^3}{3!} J_y+ ... = \cos t ~ J_x -\sin t ~J_y ~.
$$

So, what do you get by rotating an x-vector around the z-axis?